# Expected expression, Unexpected indentation, Unindent not expected in several lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi duda es con `elif`. el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Expected expression, Unexpected indentation, Unindent not expected in several lines.

Estoy atascado, el código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
print("Bienvenido a mi pequeño juego")
number = int(input("Elige un número entre 1-3: "))
if number == 1:
    print("Te encanta considerarte un líder, ¿verdad?")
number2 = float(input("Introducir un número con una cifra decimal entre 1 y 2: "))
if number2 == 2.00:
    print("¡Está bien! ¡Quise decir un poco menos que eso!")
elif number < 1.50:
    print("¡Oh, vamos! ¡Puedes ir más alto!")
else:
    print("Sabes qué, olvídalo!")
elif number == 2:
    print("Odias estar solo, ¿verdad?")
elif number == 3:
    print ("Cuanto más, mejor, ¿no?")
else:
    print("¿En serio? No puedes seguir instrucciones simples, ¿verdad?")
```

Los errores salen en las líneas: 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17. No se me ocurre que puede ser, a ver si me podéis ayudar.

Comment: Tienes un `elif` después de un `else`. Eso no tiene sentido.

Comment: el `else` en este caso pertenece al bloque "number2", no puedo utilizar `elif` con los otros números?

Comment: No se exactamente que quieres, pero la indexación no lo refleja. ¿Es algo como esto https://www.online-python.com/GLr658ON2P?

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente quisiste decir:

```
print("Bienvenido a mi pequeño juego")
number = int(input("Elige un número entre 1-3: "))
if number == 1:
    print("Te encanta considerarte un líder, ¿verdad?")
    number2 = float(input("Introducir un número con una cifra decimal entre 1 y 2: "))
    if number2 == 2.00:
        print("¡Está bien! ¡Quise decir un poco menos que eso!")
    elif number2 < 1.50: 
        print("¡Oh, vamos! ¡Puedes ir más alto!")
    else:
        print("Sabes qué, olvídalo!")
elif number == 2:
    print("Odias estar solo, ¿verdad?")
elif number == 3:
    print ("Cuanto más, mejor, ¿no?")
else:
    print("¿En serio? No puedes seguir instrucciones simples, ¿verdad?")
```

La indentación es parte de la sintaxis en Python. Indentando el código es como formas bloques de instrucciones.

Probablemente quisiste decir

```
    elif number2 < 1.50:
```

en lugar de

```
    elif number < 1.50:
```

Comment: entonces el problema por lo que veo estaba en los elif del bloque de los decimales, no?

Comment: @L127204S. No me atrevo a diagnosticar donde realmente está el problema.